# Capturing Groups REGEX Java

Tags: java, regex, capture-group

I'd like to capture the groups in my regular expression but it seems that I haven't written it as it should be. Consider the following lines:

```
String input = "username=johndoe";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)=(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
```

When I try to capture the group one and two I've got an IllegalStateExcpetion. I really don't know what's wrong with my regex, and I also tried several different ways of writing it =/.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do [find](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) or [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29) :

`matcher.matches()` or `matcher.find()`

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `IllegalStateExcpetion` because you forgot to call either:

```
matcher.matches()
```

OR

```
matcher.find()
```

You can access captured groups only after calls to either of the 2 methods shown above.